# Why are the shadows disappearing for a few frames

Tags: rendering, lighting, shadows

In this portion of a longer animation, the shadows suddenly disappear for a few frames then reappear.

[image]

This doesn't happen when I scrub thru the Timeline in the 3D window, only in the Render.  I assume I've accidentally animated something, but don't see any key frames in Timeline, Dope Sheet, or Graph Editor.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are there any hidden objects that are disabled for the viewport (eye icon) and enabled for the render (camera icon)?

Comment: its hard to guess without the blend file, light shaders, hidden objects, light setting changes

Comment: @user, I've added a link to my blend file to the post.  Note that the character animation on the timeline is in a different place from the gif, but that the shadows still dissappear in the render at approx frames 480-500. Any help would be much appreciated as this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Not entirely sure i replaced your lights it was still there, i altered your tree shader (removed that group in there) and it seemed gone (using latest alpha version of blender).